# How can I make SQLSERVER auto increment in 5 digit format?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQLSERVER my table has auto increment ID for each record, fairly straight forward.
How do I set this ID number to be always 5-digit (I am never going to go over 99999 in this table)?
So, record 1 is 00001, record 596 is 00596, 4871 is 04871,and so one... 
How can i set the 000001 formate on the Id Field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Identity with leading padded zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429284/sql-identity-with-leading-padded-zeros)

Comment: but yet - mysql or sqlserver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE T (
   _ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
   ID as RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(varchar(5),_ID),5),
   /* other columns */
)
```

Although generally, you'd want to keep formatting concerns outside of the database - especially since `IDENTITY` columns *shouldn't* be shown to users.

Comment: Massive +1 for **"keep formatting concerns outside of the database"**