# How to add leading zeros to a auto numbering ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add a "TransactionID" to a file - it will be a number that uniquely identifies each record.  Must be all numeric characters, use leading zeros to complete the field.  The data type is text with max length of 12.

So a 1 would be "000000000001" and if the number is 1657 then it should print "00000001657".

I did this but the TransactionID doesn't have leading zeros so I need help to add the leading zeros.  I'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_TOC_FINAL (
      Agency_Code VARCHAR(3)
    , Consumer_ID INT
    , Program_Area_ID INT
    , Discharge_Status VARCHAR(2)
    , Admit_Date NVARCHAR(20)
    , Discharge_Date NVARCHAR(20)
    , TransactionID INT identity (1,1) Primary key
```

The real programmer left and I'm trying my best to fix where he left off.

Thanks!

Comment: I changed the tag to SQL Server.  This is clearly not MySQL code.

Comment: I suggest you read this thread https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15052/how-do-i-preserve-the-leading-zeros-when-i-insert-a-number-into-this-table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429284/sql-identity-with-leading-padded-zeros

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server, you are in luck.  You can use computed columns.  I would put the identity column first, so the table would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_TOC_FINAL (
     TransactionID INT identity (1,1) Primary key,
     Agency_Code VARCHAR(3),
     Consumer_ID INT,
     Program_Area_ID INT,
     Discharge_Status VARCHAR(,2),
     Admit_Date NVARCHAR(20)
     Discharge_Date NVARCHAR(20), 
     TransactionId_str as (right(replicate('0', 12) + cast(TransactionID as varchar(12)), 12)
);
```

You can now use `TransactionId_str` for your output.  I should note that integers max out around 2,000,000,000 -- that is 10 digits, not 12.

Comment: can you please explain this line TransactionId_str as (right(replicate('0', 12) + cast(TransactionID as varchar(12)), 12) ?

Comment: Thanks the last line worked.  My only problem now is that the file should only have 7 columns and with the TransactionID INT identity (1,1) Primary key on the top - it counts as a column.  Is there a way to hide this?

Comment: @EFlojo . . . Not really.  You might need to use a view if you don't want the base table to seem like it has an additional column.  However, I would suggest that you list out the columns you want rather than using `*`.  That might solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Gordon!