# Padding the beginning of a mysql INT field with zeroes

Tags: mysql, int, padding

I have an INT field in a large MySQL database containing incremental numbers in an INT field. These numbers are currently regular autoincrement numbers (1, 2, 3) but I need to pad them to three digits with zeroes at the beginning (so I get 001, 002, 003.. 010, 011, etc).

What commands can I run on my database to change this column into the format I need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set autoincrement format to 0001 in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611340/how-can-i-set-autoincrement-format-to-0001-in-mysql)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add a ZEROFILL attribute to the column to pad the data in the database or, when querying,

```
SELECT LPAD(CONVERT(`col`,VARCHAR(3)),3,'0')
```

to retreive the data formatted as a 3 digit number

Comment: +1: don't mess with the data in the database, change the data into the format you happen to need when querying the database.

Comment: Agreed, always display the data differently, dont change the data in the database

Comment: I need the data to be in the three-digit format when I run the select command, which is why I wanted to change the data in the database. This should work though.

Comment: I'm using this sql: SELECT * FROM occupational_titles WHERE LPAD(CONVERT(`occupation_code`,VARCHAR(3)),3,'0') LIKE '{$category}%' LIMIT 7;, but it's throwing at error at VARCHAR. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: try puttting the LPAD in the select clause AS 'ALIAS' and then WHERE ALIAS LIKE '{category}%'

Comment: Technically, the "convert" isn't required.
    SELECT LPAD(`col`,3,'0')

Comment: If you are having problems with VARCHAR, try CHAR instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as having leading zeroes on data in a numeric field in the database; the data just isn't stored that way, any more than it is stored in roman numerals. All you've got is the number three; so if you want to get the string "003" out, you've got two options:

- Change to use a string field in the database: not recommended because you can't easily get incrementing numbers.
- Format the number as you retrieve it from the database to add leading zeroes: better, but it has its own disadvantages - e.g. comparisons will be slower because they aren't indexed.