# MYSQL column update

Tags: mysql

In mysql update the number in the column that it would be 9 digits

for example:

```
658 were recorded, but must be 000000658, 
if 96258, this must be 000096258, front contributed to 0.
```

Thanks

Comment: And what did you tried?

Comment: That's rendering. Save data in the db, leave rendering to the UI

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191494/padding-the-beginning-of-a-mysql-int-field-with-zeroes ?

Comment: use ZEROFILL attribute to the column to pad the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating column use this:

```
ALTER table `table` CHANGE `column` `column` VARCHAR(9);
```

While inserting or updating data use this:

```
UPDATE table SET `column` = LPAD(`column`, 9, '0'); #pads everything
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to change the datatype from int to varchar(9). Just have your code add on the zero's before committing to your database.
Example in PHP:

```
$foo = "604";
while(strlen($foo) < 9)
{
    $foo = "0".$foo;
}
```

$foo now equals 000000604. All you would need to do is write a loop to pull from your database and commit back to it.

Comment: i think the tag is with `mysql`