# How to store id like this 000001 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

how can I store number like this 000001 in mysql, and increment it everytime a new user register?

Answer (score 6):

You can add `zerofill` to your (`autoincrement`) id column to do what the name suggests. It will make your datatype `unsigned`.

see also

- [How can I set autoincrement format to 0001 in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611340/how-can-i-set-autoincrement-format-to-0001-in-mysql)
- [What is the benefit of zerofill in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256469/what-is-the-benefit-of-zerofill-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `ZEROFILL` attribute to the field.

```
CREATE Table tableName (
   mykey int(6) zerofill not null auto_increment, 
   primary key(mykey)
);
```

will result every new record:

```
000001
```