# Get and increase by 1 the max number in my database

Tags: php

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("select MAX(column1) FROM sampledb");

while($iii=mysql_fetch_row($sql2))

{

$iii['MAX(column1)'];

}
$numplus = $iii+1;

echo"$numplus";
```

im a newbie pls help me T_T

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for here is [the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column attribute](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html), which instructs MySQL to automatically use the next available value for a primary key.

Comment: @RobertJohnConcepcion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611340/how-can-i-set-autoincrement-format-to-0001-in-mysql

Comment: @Robert John Concepcion: don't mix the data and its presentation

Comment: UPDATE `sampledb` SET  `column1` =  'auto_increment' WHERE `id` ='$id' ei? this is posible?

Comment: $sql2 = mysql_query("select MAX(column1) FROM sampledb");

$iii=mysql_fetch_row($sql2);

echo max($iii);

$new = 1+max($iii);

echo "
$new";

mynext problem is, for example the highest # in my db is 000002, then the formula $new = 1+max($iii); ($new=000002+1), why the answer is 3 not 000003.. pls help me to do the format 000003.. plszzz Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research! http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php